# simulate onclick event in gridview in android

Tags: android

i have a gridview which is a calendar. once the user selects a date and decides to go to another activity , upon return the day he had previously selected should remain selected.

upon selecting a day the image of the gridview cell that was selected gets changed. now when the user returns , if i can simulate the onclick event , then i would not have to write extra code.

in summary, i need to simulate a onclick event on a gridview cell via code. how do i do it?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to simulate the click. You just have to store somewhere(shared preferences is ok) the day, which is choosen. If there is no such value, then no day is choosen.

So, all you need to do it to save the day and read the saved value in your `onResume()` method.

If want still reuse onClick, just move the code from onClick() method to the separate one, and call it with your onResume().

Comment: its complicated. i will have to recode the custom adapter. i just need to simulate the onclick event.

Comment: you can simply call a method. See the ipdated answer.

Comment: And how are you going to define on what day you want to simulate the click event?

Comment: i have 3 variables which i pass around with the intents called day, month, year. each and every view inside the gridview has id in the format day-month-year. so the gridview cell representing may-1 would have its id as 1-may-2011.

Comment: Ok, what is the problem of finding view by it's id?

Comment: its in a gridview. once the gridview needs to redraw itself. if i write the code in onresume method , it will try to find a view which is is not yet available....

Comment: onResume() called just after the activity became visible.

Comment: how do i find a view inside a gridview? i mean assume xyz is the object of the gridview.  i am doing xyz.findViewByTag(tag). i am not setting the id of the elements inside the gridview like i said before. i am setting the tag. anyways the above is giving me an null view.